# Does C# not allow me to group files by filter groups?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm used to grouping my C++ projects so my VS project has multiple filter groups, which do not map directly to actual directories on my disk... e.g. all my .cpp files might be in c:\code\MyApp and my 'folders' in VS split this between headers/source or graphics/sound/io and so on

In C# it doesn't seem to work this way - if I add a folder to my C# project it creates a physical directory on my disk. If I add-existing-file to this folder, it copies the file across.

Do folders replace filters in C#?

Comment: VS projects map your folders in Project to physical folders

Comment: Have you checked out [Solution Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2027y2(v=vs.100).aspx)?